# How to parse multiple value using singleton class to database in android?

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, singleton

I am building an android application where all the values are
parsedfrom URL to my app in the form of json data using volley. Now I
want to store this parsed value to my local database.

I tried to store the value in database by using the singleton class.
Now the problem that I am facing is that only the last value that was
parsed to an set function of the singleton  class, is inserted to my
local database, but rest of the values are not. I am inserting the
values to my database on the click of a button.

Here is my code where I am parsing the value from URL and set to
singleton class -

```
package tabsswipe;
public class FragmentPlay extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = FragmentPlayo.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://URL/api/user/_id/host";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Sigleton_class> movieList = new ArrayList<Sigleton_class>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
DatabaseHelper dbh;
public static ArrayList<String> array;
ImageView hostbtn;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play,
            container, false);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Sigleton_class movie = new Sigleton_class();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("venue"));
                            movie.setGender(obj.getString("gender"));
                            movie.setAddinfo(obj.getString("addinfo"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
}
```

> Here is my code of singleton class.

```
package volley_signleton_pck;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sigleton_class {
private static String title;
private String thumbnailUrl;
private static String gender;
private String recurring;
private static String addinfo;
private String players;
private String date;
private String venue;
private String time;
private String sportname;
private int year;
private double rating;
private ArrayList<String> genre;


public Sigleton_class() {
}

public Sigleton_class(String name, String thumbnailUrl, int year, double rating,String 
gender,String recurring,String addinfo,
        String player,String date,String venue,String time,String sportname,
        ArrayList<String> genre) {
    this.title = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.year = year;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.recurring = recurring;
    this.addinfo = addinfo;
    this.players = player;
    this.date = date;
    this.venue = venue;
    this.time = time;
    this.sportname = sportname;
}

public static String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public double getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(double rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}

public static String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getRecurring() {
    return recurring;
}

public void setRecurring(String recurring) {
    this.recurring = recurring;
}

public static String getAddinfo() {
    return addinfo;
}

public void setAddinfo(String addinfo) {
    this.addinfo = addinfo;
}

public String getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(String players) {
    this.players = players;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getVenue() {
    return venue;
}

public void setVenue(String venue) {
    this.venue = venue;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getSportname() {
    return sportname;
}

public void setSportname(String sportname) {
    this.sportname = sportname;
}
 }
```

> Here is my code where I insert the data from singleton class to my
>   database

```
btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            long res = dbh.addRec(Sigleton_class.getTitle(),
                    Sigleton_class.getGender(), Sigleton_class.getAddinfo());

            if (res > 0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity_DB.this);
                build.setTitle("Success");
                build.setMessage("Record inserted successfully");
                build.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                etMail.setText(" ");
                                etPword.setText(" ");
                                etMobile.setText(" ");
                            }
                        });
                build.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

> Here is my datahelper class

```
package com.example.mydatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper {
SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelper;
//Context mContext;
public static final String DB_NAME = "contact";
public static final int DB_VER = 4;

public static final String TBL_NAME = "info";
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String COL_PWORD = "password";
public static final String COL_MOBILE = "mobile";

String[] allColumns ={COL_ID, COL_EMAIL, COL_PWORD, COL_MOBILE};

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}
public void addData(List<Sigleton_class> mov) {

       for (Sigleton_class movie : mov) {
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(COL_EMAIL, movie.getTitle());
           values.put(COL_PWORD, movie.getDate());//get name
           values.put(COL_MOBILE, movie.getAddinfo());//get phone number
           //insert contact
           db.insert(TBL_NAME, COL_ID, values);
       }
       db.close();
   }
public long addRec(String email, String pword, String mobile)
{
    long i=0;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(COL_PWORD, pword);
    cv.put(COL_MOBILE, mobile);

    i=db.insert(TBL_NAME, COL_ID, cv);  

    return i;

}
public Cursor getRec(String strMail)
{
    Cursor cur = null;
    if((strMail==null)&&(strMail.length()==0))
    {
        cur = db.query(TBL_NAME, allColumns, null, null,null,null, null);
        //"like '" +name+"%'", 

    }
    else
    {

     String sel[] = {strMail+"'%'"};
    //  cur= db.query(TBL_NAME, allColumns, 
        //      COL_EMAIL+ " like '"+ strMail + "%'" ,null, null, null, null);

        cur = db.query(TBL_NAME, allColumns, COL_EMAIL+ " like ", sel, 
                null,null, null);
    }   
    return cur;

}

public long updateRec(int id, String email, String pw, String mob)
{
    long i=0;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(COL_PWORD, pw);
    cv.put(COL_MOBILE, mob);
    i=db.update(TBL_NAME, cv, COL_ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});


    return i;
}
public long  deleteRec(int id)
{
    long i=0;
    i=db.delete(TBL_NAME, COL_ID + "=?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    return i;       
}
public Cursor fetchAllRec()
{
    db= dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur= null;
    cur = db.query(TBL_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cur != null)
    {

        cur.moveToFirst();
    }   

    return cur;
}




public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String createSql = "create table " + TBL_NAME + "(" +COL_ID + 
                " INTEGER primary key autoincrement," +
                COL_EMAIL + " TEXT(50)," + COL_PWORD + " TEXT(40),"
                +COL_MOBILE + " TEXT(50))";

        Log.d("Create ", createSql);
        db.execSQL(createSql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }       
}   
}
```

Comment: try to summarize your question

Comment: Fragments, network operations together - that's always a bad idea. Use a service or asynctask.

Comment: @yaa110 I had updated my question please can you help me now

Comment: @brummfondel OK I will use asynctask. Please can you help me in solving this problem

Comment: There are many many many problems, eg. dbh is not initialized, addData() is not called (which might fill the database), addData() closes the database for all other calls, etc. Please provide the error you got, so we can start to solve the problem you got (beside them you will get later... sorry).

Comment: your `Sigleton_class` is not really a singleton class, have a look at https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992 Moreover, try to edit your question and remove codes that are not related to your problem

Comment: @brummfondel can you please tell where I should call adddata and how

Comment: @yaa110 How can I set the value to this single ton class